# How to modify product data on observer pre cache?

Tags: product, event-observer, cache, catalog

My problem would be the following:

I need to modify the product data on load after the product page was cached.

Everytime I load a product I need to request some data to an api and overwrite certain product attribute, even after it was cached.

I tried intercepting these events, but the code on my observers only gets executed the first time, then it gets cached:

`catalog_product_load_after`

`catalog_controller_product_view`

I'm open to any alternative solution btw!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`catalog_controller_product_view` event cannot be used in conjunction with FPC cache since Magento will not raise it after the first visit.

**Option 1 - The AJAX way:**

You have to:

- Create a controller accepting your product's id
- Add a JS block to your product's page calling your controller and
  passing the product's id
- Insert your tracking code in your new controller

**Option 2 - Predispatch event (not tested):**

Otherwise you could try using `controller_action_predispatch` event that should be called even with FPC enabled.

You will have to get the product's information by your own in this case.